# R / ggplot for Percent Yes of 2 categorical features

Tags: r, ggplot2

I hope I can explain this well. Suppose you have a fictitious data set that has 3 columns,

- Car
- Color
- Yes/No

Each row is an observation that indicates if the user likes their model car and color. I'd like to create chart that shows on the X axis each model car then a line graph for each color where the y value is the percent liked (yes) of the total for that combination of car/color.

What is the best approach to work this in R? I'm thinking this could be useful in general where the response is Yes/No, and you want to show an interaction between two categorical features.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're comparing two categorical variables and a quantitative variable that sums to a single value (yes/no), you probably want a bar chart?  It depends on what groups you're trying to compare - the variables, the interaction, etc.  In general, I'd go with a stacked bar chart (y/n being different factors of `geom_bar`) using `position = "dodge"` to compare different color preferences among owners of the same car model.  But like I said, I have no idea what your hypothesis or goal is with presenting these data

Comment: Without seeing your data, it's hard for us to give concrete advice. You will probably want to experiment with different combinations of facets and fill colors to see which distinctions are interesting and worth displaying in a chart.

Comment: Please share a little bit of sample data, rather than just describing data. *Probably* the best approach for what you describe is to aggregate your data by car and color - `ggplot` has some capabilities to produce summary statistics, but generally I like to use data summary tools for summarizing data and only expect my visualization tools to visualize the data I give it, not summarize it too.

Comment: Thanks for the comments above. I think I was able to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is what I ended up doing. It seems to do what I need it to do ;0

PS - I'm not sure if it's appropriate to answer my own question. Thanks for the comments!

```
prop <- data.frame(prop.table(table(data$outcome,data$Factor1,data$Factor2),3))
names(prop) <- c("Outcome","Factor1","Factor2","Percentage")

# Remove No Percent
prop <- prop[which(prop$Outcome=="Yes"),]

# Bar plot
ggplot(data=prop, aes(x=Factor1, y=Percentage, fill=Factor2)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  theme_minimal()

# Line Plot
ggplot(data=prop, aes(x=Factor1, y=Percentage, group=Factor2)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=Factor2))+
  geom_point(aes(color=Factor2))
```